# How to know whether solution build in debug or release mode using .sln file?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, projects-and-solutions, solution, visual-studio-2017-build-tools

I have .sln file and I want to know whether the projects of that solution built in debug or release mode using .sln file.
Is there any way to find the mode?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? You want to know _after the fact_ if projects were built (not will be built) using the "release" or "debug" configuration?

Comment: .sln does not give any information to what the compiled mode was during compilation.  It does contain information related to the debug and production types of builds supported by the project.  But in an .sln a project can be ether or its about what is set when compiled.